# Creating a table from the result of ST_DumpValues()

Tags: raster, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have, I believe, successfully loaded a raster into my PG DB. I see the table in PGAdmin but am unable to see it in QGIS. The table in PG has 1 row. Running, e.g. `st_count(rast)` on the table returns over 600,000. I am,

1. Unable to view the dataset in QGIS
2. Unable to run PG raster function (e.g. `ST_DumpValues`, `ST_Aspect`).

There is obviously a first step to do after loading data to the database that I am missing. I cannot find info related to this anywhere. What is it that I am missing?

```
CREATE TABLE raster1 AS SELECT
 ST_DumpValues(ST_Aspect(rast, 1, '32BF'))
 FROM raster
```

Gives me,

> ERROR: column "st_dumpvalues" has pseudo-type record

Comment: Could it be that you did not yet enable the PostGIS extension in your database? Run the following command: `create extension postgis;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PostgreSQL you have to specify type in set-returning-functions as [`ST_DumpValues()`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpValues.html) returns a `setof` `nband, valarray` we can do that like this,

```
CREATE TABLE raster1
AS
  SELECT nband, valarray
  FROM raster
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_DumpValues(ST_Aspect(rast, 1, '32BF'))
    AS dv(nband, valarray);  -- specifying return type of ST_DumpValues
```

For more information see my question on Database Administrators, [*How do you `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS)` with a composite type?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158633/2639).

Comment: I am still unable to view result in QGIS. Why? Also, there is no rast (geometry) field now and I still only have 1 row (is there only ever supposed to be one row of data with rasters?)

Comment: No idea on that one. same scale/skew/srid?

Comment: yeah... it isn't showing up in the tree. Any thoughts on the lack of geometry in your query? The code ran and produced 1 row with no geometry field.

Comment: ST_DumpValues doesn't produce a geometry? Is this what you're trying to display in QGIS? Dumpvals produces the bands as 2d arrays.

Comment: I figured it out. I was working along with the example from https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Aspect.html . Working with tables in PG so much, I thought that the st_DumpValues was like st_Dump and created many rows of data. I now have the raster data in QGIS, though had to add it through DB manager as it still doesn't show up in tree view. Sorry, just getting going on working with raster data in PG